# Searching by the first letter of each word in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am wondering is there any filter available that will serve the following functionality.
suppose there is only one field which is of type string/Text.

and this field has the following data.

```
"Apple Banana Cat"
"Apple Banana Cat Dog"
"Zodiac Apple Banana Cat"
```

and if user query *(input)*:

```
ABC
```

what I expect is to return data that match the first letter of each word.

the output should be like

```
"Apple Banana Cat"
"Apple Banana Cat Dog"
```

please suggest to me if there any build-in filters is available to achieve this functionality in solr.

what I am thinking is like to achieve this
[image]
It is just for fun,
happy to have your thoughts and opinion on it.
thank you.

Comment: you can try this by adding the synonyms...ABC apple banana cat...

Comment: If you can live with having in-string matches (so `BC` is generated as well), the Shingle Filter will do what you want: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/filter-descriptions.html#shingle-filter

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti yes sir, using synonyms can solve the problem,
like I will have map all the possible data which could be related to ABC like 
`
"Apple", "Amazon", .... -> A
"Apple Banana", "Apple Boy", "Amazon Brb", .... -> AB
"Apple Banana Cat", "Apple Boy Car", "Amazon Brb Car", .... -> ABC
`
but this will create two problems 1st is the maintenance of this synonym.txt file and the 2nd is the scaling. what would be the size of this file if we have 10MM documents.
thanks for your suggestion.